# how to presist browser network logs in webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using:

```
firefox version 58.0.1
geckodriver version 0.11.1
selenium-c# r.2.53.0
```

Am trying to presist browser network logs though webdriver by setting up the firefoxProfile.SetPreference, 
How can i actually do that ?.

Comment: You want `logs` of your `WebDriver` execution?

Comment: I want to presist and capture browser network logs using webdriver.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BrowserMob Proxy`. It is an open source tools which is used to capture performance data for a web applications in an `HAR` format. It also allows to manipulate browser behavior and traffic, such as simulating network traffic, rewriting HTTP requests and responses etc.

This link might help you with your question: [BrowserMob Proxy Tutorial](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/browsermob-proxy-selenium-example)

It shows the complete working of this API and how to view the generated `.har` file.

Hope this helps.